# Is it possible to use eager loading with the querybuilder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image: Querybuilder object]

As one can see above, there is a 'eagerLoad' section and the querybuilder accepts calling `$query->with('relation')` but produces the following error: `Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.`

I've tried to find some documentation on this matter but didn't find much. Is it possible at all to use eager loading in this case? If so, could anyone tell how?

**Update**

As some people pointed out it is possible and the error is caused by another error in my code. Here are some samples:

```
// Querybuilder
$query->select([
    'persons.id as alumni_id',
    ...
]);

$query->where('...'); // Based on search parameters
$query->groupBy('alumni_id');

$query->with('relation');

$result = collect($query->get());

// Model
public function relation()
{
    // Note: relation does have a column person_id
    return $this->hasMany(Relation::class, 'person_id', 'alumni_id')->get();
}
```

Produces

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've learned, It is not possible to use eager loading to load Model relations with the querybuilder. (as the querybuilder is not leveraging Eloquent, it doesn't know about the relations) 
If anyone knows this to be (partially) incorrect, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
// Querybuilder
$query->select([
    'persons.id as alumni_id',
    ...
]);

$query->where('...'); // Based on search parameters
$query->groupBy('alumni_id');

$query->with('relation');

$result = $query->get(); // already returns a collection

// Model
public function relation()
{
    // Note: relation does have a column person_id
    // A relation should return an Eloquent object (HasMany in this case), not a collection
    return $this->hasMany(Relation::class, 'person_id', 'alumni_id');
}
```